# Как создать приложение для Mac OS X в среде Visual Studio Code на машине c ОС Linux?

Tags: .net-core

Возможно ли откомпилировать программу для .net 5 на ПК с Linux для использования на Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень зависит от типа. Консольное - написать можно, но собирать придётся на mac (можно установить VM с Mac OS, если очень важно). GUI же не работает на .NET Core, так что очень сомнительна возможность это сделать. Связанный вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649976/is-it-possible-to-make-desktop-gui-application-in-net-core